# How to move tables to another postgres schema using liquibase without running queries inside schema again?

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, liquibase

I have `db-service` with all the changelog files. When running `db-service` for the first time all the tables will be created in the `public schema`. Then tables will be filled with initial data.

[image] db-service

[image] db-service

Now we have decided to split `db-service` and distribute changelog files between services. So in the microservice I have created the same structure of folders.

I moved changelog files to `info-service`. And now I need to move tables into a separate schema, but I can't do it until tables aren't filled with init data. So I've created new folder and added additional path in root.changelog.

[image] info-service

[image] info-service

My changesets look like:

[image] 230105-initial-changelog.xml

I run this changeset with URL `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres` and everything works fine, tables are moved to another schema.

But then I modify data source URL to start working in my info-microservice with specific schema:
`spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres?currentSchema=info_schema`

And when I run my service for the second time with currentSchema URL parameter I get `ERROR: relation "atm" already exists` and `ERROR: relation "contacts" already exists`. So liquibase wants to start doing all the changes from the beginning in the info-schema. It tries to create, init and alter tables again.

How to let Liquibase know that it shouldn't create tables in my schema? Note that i can't change old changelogfiles from the `structure folder`

Comment: [liquibase-schema-name](https://docs.liquibase.com/parameters/liquibase-schema-name.html). In short: since default schema is managed by jdbc driver, liquibase does not see previous `DATABASECHANGELOG` table and tries to reapply old migrations. You need to specify correct schema where the actual `DATABASECHANGELOG` table is located via `spring.liquibase.liquibase-schema`. BTW, being in your shoes I would stay clear off schemas.

Comment: Thanks, it worked out! but also in my case i had to add ```spring.liquibase.url```